# Call a V2 Module from V1 User Event

Tags: netsuite

I'm in the process of upgrading code in a NetSuite account. However, some of the code in the account is still v1.

I want to use a v2 utility module that I wrote from one of the existing v1 User Event scripts.

Is it possible to include the v2 module in a v1 script?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your record in Suitescript 1.0, it would expect the syntax and api in that version, so all the functionality/modules in 2.0 will not be interpreted and you will get an error. You need to migrate to UE code to 2.0